# How to ffill nan values in a numpy array using the last non-nan values repeating N times

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I would like to ffill nan values in a numpy array using the last non-nan values repeating N times. If the number of nan values > N, then fill the rest nan values with zero. How do I do it in pure numpy without iteration?

```
import numpy as np

n = 2
arr = np.array([np.nan, 0, 0, np.nan, 5, 4, 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 5, 3, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan])

def ffill(arr: np.array, n: int):
    pass
    return arr

result = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0])
```

Ffill 4 n times (=2) [... 4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan ...] -> [... 4, 4, 4, 0 ...]

[Solution]

Thanks for @Homer512 's answer. I improved it when n is very large.

```
def ffill(arr: np.array, n: int):
    if np.isnan(arr[0]):
        arr[0] = 0

    isnan = np.isnan(arr)
    notnan = ~isnan
    valid = arr[notnan]
    indices = np.cumsum(notnan) - 1
    arr = valid[indices]

    overlimit = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(isnan[:-1][::-1], isnan.size-n)[:, ::-1].all(axis=0)
    overlimit &= isnan[n:]

    indices = np.flatnonzero(overlimit) + n
    arr[indices] = 0
    return arr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick that works:

1. Fix the start value

```py
if math.isnan(arr[0]):
    arr[0] = 0
```

2. Now we can keep track of the valid indices with np.cumsum

```py
isnan = np.isnan(arr)
notnan = ~isnan
valid = arr[notnan]
indices = np.cumsum(notnan) - 1
arr = valid[indices]
```

3. To support your requirement that NaNs are replaced with zeros after N steps, you could use `np.convolve(isnan, (1,) * (n + 1), mode='same') > n` to find the indices. But because convolve is centered, it's a bit complicated to find the correct index from the convolution. Let's do it manually instead. Yes, this will use an iteration, but only a fixed number for N

```py
overlimit = np.copy(isnan[n:])
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    overlimit &= isnan[n-i:-i]
indices = np.flatnonzero(overlimit) + n
arr[indices] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But it has a small mistake, your answer is [0. 0. 0. 0. 5. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 1. 5. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2.], and the target array should be [0. 0. 0. 0. 5. 4. 4. 4. 4. 0. 1. 5. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2.]

Comment: @wuya Edited the answer to provide the functionality

Comment: I improved your method a little bit and posted it above